# Android: need help to create UI

Tags: android

In my app I want to create something like this: [like this](http://picasaweb.google.it/dr.cervo/Develop?feat=email#5503703287992443698):

[image]

I thought to put five buttons inside a linear layout, but the problem is how to show the inner items at run time. Every time i click on a button i want to show the proper items and hide the others.

Answer (score 1):

I've never had the pleasure of using them, but I think `ExpandableListView` might be what will help you. 
You can find documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).
And a nice example with sample you can use [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html).

Comment: Thanks. i try with ExpandableListView